# Resize UIImage in Place

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, image-processing, uiimage

I have a category (very popular code found on web) to `UIImage` to do various image manipulation.

```
- (UIImage *)imageScaledToSize:(CGSize)newSize {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(newSize);
    [self drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, newSize.width, newSize.height)];
    UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();    
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return newImage;
}
```

One aspect that I am making heavy use of is scaling an image down. My app can take quite large images and scales them down to a "working" size. However, there are still times when the app crashes due to memory. This is because the category creates a **new** scaled image from the original. Therefore, the original HUGE image is still resident while the new smaller (but still big) image is created.

So, my question is, is there a way to load this large original image and rescale it in place? That is, rescale the original without creating a new image, and not allocing more memory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, and there is even a complete working Apple [sample project](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/LargeImageDownsizing/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40011173) that does this for you.

As far as I know there is no limitation on what size image it can scale down. Of course though, the larger the image the more time consuming the process is.